# two finger scrolling won't work; ubuntu mate 15.04

Tags: 15.04, touchpad, multi-touch, mate

I am running Ubuntu mate 15.04 in a VMware player, and am trying to get the two finger scrolling to work. I have Synaptics Touchpad V1.4 and it works in my host OS (windows 8). I've tried editing the touchpad settings in dconf. 
[dconf touchpad settings (set to enable two finger scrolling)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60lYR.png)
I noticed that Synaptics touchpad doesn't show up when I type xinput in the terminal
[xinput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9phj.png)
Even though I installed the Synaptics Touchpad Driver for the x.org server.
I even tried installing gpointing device settings, but two finger scrolling still does not work. I am fairly new to linux so I have no idea what is going on... Help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Actually finger scrolling wasn't supported by vmware,
If you install Linux normally(Dual-boot), Then you don't even need a driver to scroll. Almost all Linux Distro's supports two finger scrolling.
So the problem is with Vmware, not with any Linux Distro.